# Wordpress Multiple Group Category Filter

Tags: wordpress, categories

How can I implement multiple group category filter using a widget?

Example Category Hierarchy:

Category1: Choicea1a and Choice2a

Category2: Choice1b and Choice2b

I want to display the two categories inside a select field containing their respective child categories. Is there an existing plugin for this?

Thanks!